# Download a .zip file from the command line

Tags: curl, download, zip

I've been somewhat blindly trying lots of variations of `curl` and `wget` to try downloading some `.zip` files.  The first thing I tried was this:

```
curl --klo ".\bhcdata#1.zip" "https://www.chicagofed.org/applications/bhc_data/bhcdata_create_output.cfm?DYR=2011&DQTR=[1-4]"
```

The command above is in fact provided [in the documentation by the Chicago Fed](http://www.chicagofed.org/webpages/banking/financial_institution_reports/bhc_data.cfm), and yet it throws error messages on my Ubuntu machine: `curl: option --klo: is unknown`.

Is there a straightforward way to do this?

**To clarify exactly what I'm trying to do:**  The Chicago Fed [website](https://www.chicagofed.org/applications/bhc_data/bhcdata_index.cfm) lets you enter a year and quarter, and you click "Download data file" and it gives you a .zip file of the corresponding data.  I want to do this for all quarters, so I need a way to write the command for each quarter so that I can loop over them.  The `[1-4]` in the example command above would grab all four quarters in one year, but I'd be fine with just getting one quarter at a time, and I've tried replacing `1` as well.  I've tried with and without various combinations of options, but nothing has worked yet.

Comment: what do you want the options to do for you?

Comment: @Floris, do my new comments above help to clarify?  To reiterate, I'm just trying to find a way to download a file from command line -- nevermind getting it perfect with options.

Comment: Could it be as simple as `curl -klo` etc.? You are using the double dash `--` this is for "long" commands. The single dash `-` commands `-k`= insecure (no https), `-l`=list only (used for FTP to get directory listing), `-o`= write to output file might be what you wanted... But the combination of a `https://` protocol and `-k` switch doesn't make much sense I have to say.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On my machine, the following command worked just fine:

```
curl -o ./bhcdata1.zip "https://www.chicagofed.org/applications/bhc_data/bhcdata_create_output.cfm?DYR=2011&DQTR=1"
```

Note:

1. single dash instead of double dash
2. I only specified the output file - with no quotes and with forward slash
3. I simplified the URL to a specific quarter only

I found a file named `bhcdata1.zip` in my directory when I was done:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 floris  floris    1545868 Feb 13 21:05 bhcdata1.zip
```

You might find you need the `-k` flag as well… although I didn't need to on my machine. Then it would be

```
curl -ko ./bhcdata1.zip "https://www.chicagofed.org/applications/bhc_data/bhcdata_create_output.cfm?DYR=2011&DQTR=1"
```

worked equally well...

**BONUS** to get all four quarters, you can simply put the following lines in a script. Save it as `downloadAll`. Change the file to "executable" with `chmod 755 downloadAll` , then type `./downloadAll`. Enjoy…

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..4}
do
  curl -ko ./bhcdata$i.zip "https://www.chicagofed.org/applications/bhc_data/bhcdata_create_output.cfm?DYR=2011&DQTR=$i"
done
```

Result:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 floris  floris    1545868 Feb 13 21:11 bhcdata1.zip
-rw-r--r--   1 floris  floris    2413876 Feb 13 21:11 bhcdata2.zip
-rw-r--r--   1 floris  floris    1573810 Feb 13 21:11 bhcdata3.zip
-rw-r--r--   1 floris  floris    2500525 Feb 13 21:12 bhcdata4.zip
```

and if you wanted multiple years, do (some variant of)

```
#!/bin/bash
for yr in {2010..2012}
do
  for qtr in {1..4}
  do
    curl -ko ./bhcdata$yr_$qtr.zip "https://www.chicagofed.org/applications/bhc_data/bhcdata_create_output.cfm?DYR=$yr&DQTR=$qtr"
  done
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have the wrong URL. Try

```
wget "https://www.chicagofed.org/applications/bhc_data/bhcdata_create_output.cfm?DYR=2013&DQTR=1"
```

You should be able to loop the year and quarter then

Answer (score 0):

The following bash script is my end product:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1986..2011}
do
  for j in {1..4}
  do
  curl -ko year${i}month${j}.zip "https://www.chicagofed.org/applications/bhc_data/bhcdata_create_output.cfm?DYR=$i&DQTR=$j"
  done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
curl file_name_url.zip -O -J -L
```