# Curl not working when downloading zip file from github

Tags: linux, curl

I tried to download a zip file from github (~50Mb size).

The command used was:

```
curl https://github.com/bhishanpdl/DMstack_obsfile_example/blob/master/example/trial00_good_fits.zip -L -o a.zip
curl -OLJ https://github.com/bhishanpdl/DMstack_obsfile_example/blob/master/example/trial00_good_fits.zip 
curl https://github.com/bhishanpdl/DMstack_obsfile_example/blob/master/example/trial00_good_fits.zip -OLJ
```

When I look at the downloaded file it is about ~30KB and when I unzip it, it is 
not the file I am looking for.

When I download the zip file from website directly, I am able to download the 
correct zip file (when I unzip I get 50Mb fits file).

**Question**
How can we we the above zip file from github using `curl` command ?

**Reference**
http://www.compciv.org/recipes/cli/downloading-with-curl/
[Download a .zip file from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21768455/download-a-zip-file-from-the-command-line)

**Note**
I am using Macos EL Capitan and I don't have `wget`.

Comment: `When I look at the downloaded file it is about ~30KB`. Have you looked **inside** that file?

Comment: yes, its 8kb file `trial00_good_fits.zip.cpgz`

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski, the downloaded file is not the one I was looking for. It is some nonsense file.

Comment: no, it's not. It's HTML

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The download URL is slightly different. Try -

```
curl https://github.com/bhishanpdl/DMstack_obsfile_example/raw/master/example/trial00_good_fits.zip -L -o a.zip
```